# Django issue with urls.py about / after path

Tags: html, django, django-urls

I'm starting to learn about **DJANGO** in one course.
And I have my HTML and views.py working good, just if I use the / after the path::
`path("create/", views.create, name="create")`.
In my video aulas I saw that the people usually don't put this /, but if I try like that:
`path("create", views.create, name="create")` I have the error 404 Page not found even using ***/create*** in my URL.
So, why seems that is just me who need's to use this ( / ) ??

Comment: You must have made some other mistake.  Without seeing your full code, we can only guess.

Comment: `/` is important to give at the end of every `route`, also in `HttpResponseRedirect()`.

Comment: The code in my views.py is the most simple for now. ```def create(request):
    return render(request, "auctions/create.html")```.